# Is there a keyboard shortcut to scroll through matching field recorder channels?

Tags: pro-tools, track, matching

i did a quick google search but haven't had any luck..

just looking for a command that will let me change the field recorder channels of the selected clip.

this would speed things up for me a lot.

cheers

EDIT: sorry… Im refering to Pro tools on mac. using PT 10 or PT 11 and devices are just keyboard and mouse… I'm looking for something similar to how you alter clip gain with control+shift+ up or down. but with switching the 'matching field recorder' channels

Comment: On what device/software? You really need to explain this better for anyone to be able answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Command + Option + Up or Down Arrows will scroll through available mics / channels here.

I'm on PT 10.3.5 (OSX)

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. Mouse clicks are required to replace a clip with other field recorder channels. It's a good idea though, and would be worth posting to the Pro Tools Ideascale.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure if it would work, you might be able to finagle a solution using QuickKeys?